# Remove common letters in strings

Tags: python, string

So I have an interesting problem.

I'm trying to write some word jumbles, and I need to know which letters I've used and which I haven't. So far I have the code below:

```
def remove_common(x,y):
   sort = sort = lambda x: "".join(c for c in sorted(x.lower()) if c.isalpha())
   x,y  = sort(x), sort(y)
   //some code that removes y from x
   return leftovers

print remove_common("Lets chat about code","that cool cat")
print remove_common("A silly word","a lil sword")
print remove_common("The Thing","Height")

>>> "bdeesu"
>>> "iy"
>>> "tn"
```

What I'm looking for a simple way to remove the letters that are in both, but leave duplicates where necessary.

1. Strings are converted to lower-case, non letters are deleted
2. Duplicates matter, so if `x = "aa"` and `y = "a"`, then the result is `"a"`, not `""`. This precludes the use of sets, I think.
3. If a letter is in y that's not in x, it should say this loudly.
4. Speed isn't important, but the elegance of code is. So the nicer the code is to read the better - kind of subjective I know.
5. Output order isn't important, as I can just convert to a string and `sorted()` it.

**I have looked at other answers, but these are mostly related to only giving the letters that don't appear in one and drop duplicates.**

Comment: Could you please add some more input/output examples?

Comment: @Haidro 2 more added.

Comment: @Haidro: I don't understand your first example: why isn't it `bcdeloostu`? What happened to the `o`'s, the `l`, and the third `t`? In the second exaple, why wasn't the `i` subtracted?

Comment: You say duplicates matter, but your first example has duplicate occurrences of "a". Do you mean *adjacent* duplicates?

Comment: @2rs2ts: That part makes sense to me, because there are two `a`s in the first and 2 `a`s in the second

Comment: `If a letter is in y that's not in x, it should say this loudly.` In your first example, `v` is in y but not `x`. Why don't you have it "saying anything loudly"?

Comment: @Haidro Whoops you are right, the first example is wrong, I had to remove letters by hand. Now you can understand my dilemma!

Comment: I don't know why you're addressing me :p. It was @DavidRobinson who pointed it out, and I think he accidentally pinged me

Comment: @Haidro: Oh, I'm very sorry. It looks like everyone is accidentally pinging you.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Hah it's fine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter` objects, which can be subtracted from each other:

```
import collections

def remove_common(x,y):
    count = lambda x: collections.Counter(c for c in x.lower() if c.isalpha())
    cx, cy = count(x), count(y)
    diff  = cx - cy
    rev_diff = cy - cx
    assert len(rev_diff) == 0, "%s in y and not x" % "".join(rev_diff.elements())

    return "".join(sorted(diff.elements()))
```

As a demonstration of what's happening:

```
>>> c1 = collections.Counter("hello world")
>>> c2 = collections.Counter("hey worlds")
>>> c1 - c2
Counter({'l': 2, 'o': 1})
>> (c1 - c2).elements()
['l', 'l', 'o']
```

Comment: I may have read too much into it... but it sounded like he wanted to preserve order(+1) for counter all the same

Comment: Ouput order isn't important, I'll update the rules to state this.

Comment: @JoranBeasley: No, otherwise he wouldn't have sorted each string to start with

Answer (score 1):

`collections.Counter` will not let any count go below zero if you use the `-` operator. However, if you use c.subtract(d), then it will allow you to do so. Further, when using c.elements(), values with negative counts are ignored.

Here is an implementation which is based on collections.Counter:

```
import collections                                                              

def remove_common(x, y):                                                        
    sort = lambda x: "".join(c for c in sorted(x.lower()) if c.isalpha())       
    x, y = list(sort(x)), list(sort(y))                                         
    cx = collections.Counter(x)                                                 
    cy = collections.Counter(y)
    cx.subtract(cy)

    result = ""
    for letter, count in cx.iteritems():
        for i in range(abs(count)):
            result += letter

    return result
```

I ran it on the following test sets:

```
print remove_common("Lets chat about code","that cave")                     
print remove_common("basdf aa", "a basd")                                   
print remove_common("asdfq", "asdf")                                        
print remove_common("asdf", "asdfq")                                        

print remove_common("aa bb s", "a bbb")
```

The results:

```
cbedloosutv
af
q
q
asb
```

To detect letters which are in y but not in x, you should compare the result of `cy.subtract(cx)` to the value of `cy`. For example:

```
cz = collections.Counter(cy) # because c.subtract(..) modifies c
cz.subtract(cx)
for letter, count in cz.iteritems():
    if count == cy[letter]: # in the case that there were none of letter in x
        assert False
```

The other solutions to this bit that I've seen also fail if a letter exists in y but is repeated more times than in x (for example: 'hi there' and 'hii' would produce an AssertionError in Josh Smeaton's solution but not this one). Your requirement a bit ambiguous in this regard IMO. The beauty of stackoverflow is that there are enough answers to pick your poison, though.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't handle failing on letters in `y` that are not in `x`

Comment: Ah, good catch. I misread that requirement. In that case, using the combination of cx - cy and cy - cx seems to be the way to go.

Comment: @J.DavidSmith: Your solution could handle this by doing `if(count) < 0: raise...` I do like mine, but I think this may be more efficient since it performs only a single subtraction. (However, using string concatenation is a bit slower than `"".join`, so who knows).

Comment: @DavidRobinson: `if count < 0: raise...` fails in the scenario where string X has N of letter L, while Y has M of letter L where N < M. The letter L is in both strings, but string Y has more of it and so `count < 0 == True`. As I stated in my post it's unclear which he wanted; others provided the solution where count < 0 raises an exception, so I provided the alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Building on David Robinsons' answer:

```
import collections.Counter as C
def remove_common(x,y):
    s1,s2=filter(str.isalpha, x.lower()),filter(str.isalpha, y.lower())
    c1,c2 = C(s1),C(s2)
    if any(c2-c1):
        assert False
    return list((c1-c2).elements())

>>> remove_common('hi there','hi')
['h', 'r', 'e', 'e', 't']
>>> x,y='Lets chat about code','that cool cat'
>>> remove_common(x,y)
['u', 's', 'b', 'e', 'e', 'd']
>>> remove_common('hi','ho')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in remove_common
AssertionError
```